# When web-container create instance of servlet

Tags: servlets

I dont understand does web-container create servlet's instance when web-app is deployed or this instance of servlet will be created just after server get request from client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends upon your servlet definition in web.xml.

If you specify the load-on-startup element the container will pre-load your servlet.

If you do not specify load-on-startup, the container will defer the creation of the servlet until it is needed.

From the Oracle documentation:

*The optional content of this element is an integer indicating the order in which the Servlet is to be loaded and initialized with respect to the Web application's other Servlets. An empty  indicates that the order is irrelevant, as long as the Servlet is loaded and initialized during the startup of its containing web application.*

Example: See below.  The container will first pre-load FooServlet and the BarServlet, but will not load BingServlet until it is needed.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FooServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>Foo Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>com.foo.FooServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet> 
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>BarServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>Bar Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>com.bar.BarServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet> 
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>BingServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>Bing Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>com.bing.BingServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```